# Reading INI files section starting with a comment in Delphi returns an empty list

Tags: delphi, ini

Simplified Delphi code:

```
var
    AppSettings: TIniFile;
    Camera: TStringList;

begin
    AppSettings := TIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, '.ini'));
    Camera := TStringList.Create;

    AppSettings.ReadSectionValues('Camera', Camera);

    FreeAndNil(Camera);
    FreeAndNil(AppSettings);
end;
```

Simplified INI file contents:

```
[Camera]
; A commented line
SomeKey=SomeValue
AnotherKey=AnotherVal
```

At the moment the `TStringList` is empty because of the commented line at the start of the section in the INI but I would expect to have a `Count` of 2.

Is there a way to load sections of the INI file where commented lines (`;`) are present in Delphi?

I'm using Delphi 10.3.2 on Windows 10. The line endings of the INI file are `#13#10` (`\r\n`).

Comment: Works fine here with Delphi 10.3.2. Please indicate which version you are using.

Comment: Also works fine in Delphi 10.2.3 and Delphi 2007. But I can remember having the same issue with ``TIniFile`` sometimes in the past. When I used ``TMemIniFile`` instead it worked flawlessly!

Comment: In 10.3.2+ source\data\ems\rsconsole\RSConfig.ConfigDM.pas contains code that reads an INI file with comments intact through LoadFromFile into a TFDMemTable where you can edit it and then write it back out with SaveToFile.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the line endings (LF vs CRLF) in the inifile?

Comment: You should always use TMemIniFile to avoid the deprecated and heavily shimmer API that TIniFile is based on

Comment: Both, TIniFile (and TMemIniFile) ignore (and delete when saving) all lines that start with a simicolon. This is a major annoyance, but should not be the cause for the problem you are expiriencing In your case I suspect that the INI file does not use the correct line endings, so for the INI-Parser the line after the semicolon includes both lines after that line. Check with a hex viewer which line endings are being used.

Comment: Or, e.g. with Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replaced `TIniFile` with `TMemIniFile` in the example above and now `ReadSectionValues` returns the correct result.